# How to pass a parameter to a command that's being executed by exec in bash?

Tags: bash, process, exec

I'm trying to start a subprocess with a unique process name from a bash script. This works:

```
bash -c "exec -a MyUniqueProcessName './start_service' &"
```

but my problem is that I want to pass a parameter to `start_service`. If I do something like

```
bash -c "exec -a MyUniqueProcessName './start_service param' &"
```

or

```
bash -c "exec -a MyUniqueProcessName './start_service $myvar' &"
```

then it fails with complaining about

```
/start_service param: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec` takes the utility and its arguments as *separate* arguments:

```bash
bash -c "exec -a MyUniqueProcessName './start_service' 'param1' 'param2' 'etc.' &"
```

Testing on OpenBSD:

```bash
$ bash -c 'exec -a hello sleep 5 &' && pgrep -lf hello
1898 hello 5
```

```bash
$ bash -c 'exec -a hello sleep 5 &' && ps -a | grep hello
18164 p1  Sp       0:00.01 hello 5 (sleep)
26417 p1  R+/0     0:00.01 grep hello
```

Same tests on Ubuntu (we get something called `sleep` back, but we get it when querying for `hello`, which should be ok; Linux is a mixed bag of wierdness):

```bash
$ bash -c 'exec -a hello sleep 5 &' && pgrep -lf hello
2849889 sleep
```

Note the addition of `-f` to `ps` here:

```bash
$ bash -c 'exec -a hello sleep 5 &' && ps -af | grep hello
myself  2851359       1  0 17:41 pts/0    00:00:00 hello 5
myself  2851361 2848295  0 17:41 pts/0    00:00:00 grep hello
```

Comment: Is it possible to call a local function here? So instead of calling my other script file can I call my `function start_service` ?

Comment: I just ran the script you posted and this still prints to the stdout instead of returning immediately. I tried putting the `&` both inside the `""`s and outside of it but it didn't help. It fixes the other problem though!

Comment: I just noticed that this doesn't create a process (checked with `ps`) with a unique name, and killing the process with `pkill` will not terminate *its* subprocesses either (I'm starting a `node` process in that script)

Comment: Wonder if the `&"` at the end should be `" &` in keeping with the original poster's question, even if it doesn't really matter

Comment: @ChrisDavies Yes, that would be cleaner, but I think the end result would be the same, right? Need to test first...

Comment: I tested both and neither work unfortunately

Comment: I also don't see the unique name added to the process

Comment: @ChrisDavies Moving the `&` out to the "outer" `bash -c` command leaves the command as a job in the shell it seems.  I'm not changing that as it may be unwanted.

Comment: @AdamArold Please be more specific. What do you in your first comment mean by "does not work"?  The process certainly changes names when I try it. EDIT: I've added a test in the answer, to show that it works.

Comment: @AdamArold Sorry, I did not see your initial comments at first. If you have further clarifications to the question, then please edit the question. As for `pkill`, you have to use `pkill -f` to match against the full set of command arguments I believe.

Comment: Ok, technically the parameter passing works, but I have another problem.

Comment: @AdamArold You may want to ask a new question about that. You could link to this question or answer as reference.

Comment: I just did on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @AdamArold In that question, you'd better describe what stops you from using the value `$!` (the PID of the most recently started background job), because that will be the first thing people will suggest that you use.